# Batch insertion Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-0.7

How could i realize batch insertion in Cassandra to populate with data?

Comment: 1, Are you using a high level client? 2, Are you experiencing problems during batch inserts with the client (could be raw thrift) you are using?

Comment: im using cassandra-cli.
do you know a high level client, this will so helpfull for me :)

Answer (score 2):

Use one of the clients here: http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ClientOptions

Exact syntax for batches depends on the language and client.